# Problems running Airflow on a Droplet server with supervisor

Tags: python, gunicorn, airflow, droplet

I have a small ETL to configure for which it was decided to use Airflow within a server. Airflow scheduler and webserver is started using supervisor and I get no error when doing so, supervisorctl status shows:

```
airflow-scheduler                RUNNING   pid 6007,  uptime 0:08:53
airflow-webserver                RUNNING   pid 6017,  uptime 0:08:46
app                              RUNNING   pid 21737, uptime 1
```

The Problem is:

Scheduler runs fine with supervisor but webserver running at `0.0.0.0` port `9000` is running but whenever I go to check it directly from my browser I get connection timeout.

- I've checked logs and error from supervisor for the process that runs the webserver and everything seems to be ok.

If I check `myserverdomain:9000/admin/` I get nothing or connection timeout.

Any recommendation?

Comment: are you able to access the web ui via `curl localhost:9000/admin/` on the SSH terminal? i.e prints a bunch of HTML text. if the previous succeeds, try accessing `http://<droplet-external-ip>:9000/admin to see if you can load the UI`   This is to confirm that you can access the webui and validate if this is a DNS issue with your domain

Comment: Yes, i get the html for :midropletip:port/admin/ using curl but i get connection time out when loading the same url from chrome not using curl within the server. Caould it be the nginx .conf ?

Comment: based on you comment above, seem airflow is configure properly and an intermediate service(nginx) is the issue. I would recommend double checking the `nginx ` configs are correct.